# insert data with spaces from database into an array

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to insert this kind of data from database into an array?

```
Mouse
Keyboard  //Saved from a Textarea box 
Monitor
```

The whole table looks like this;

```
id  ||   Owner  ||  Items
--------------------------
1   ||   John   || Mouse
    ||          || Keyboard //This is in a single row
    ||          || Monitor
--------------------------
```

How to assign each line of the data from field "Items" into an array (let's say $items)?

So that it will be like:

```
  $items[0] = "Mouse";
  $items[1] = "Keyboard";
  $items[2] = "Monitor";
```

Comment: So you want it to appear as though `John` is the owner of the mouse, keyboard, and monitor, or that they keyboard and mouse have no owner? or just have a list of items?

Comment: All those three items are Johns but nevermind. I got my answers already. Thanks to Vishal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$items = explode("\n", $string_from_db);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Or [PDOStatement::fetchAll()](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Or [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstand my question.

Comment: @HafizAbdullah - I think we are all misunderstanding your question. What do you want the final PHP array to look like?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$arr = explode("\n",$data);   // split into lines
$categories = explode("||",$arr[0]);
unset($arr[0]); array_values($arr[0]);  // dont want categories anymore
array_walk($categories,create_function('&$v','$v = trim($v);'));   // trim space from categories
$data = array();   // holds info
foreach((array)$arr as $key=>$val) {
   if (substr($val,0,5)=="-----") { continue; }   // ignore "-----..." lines
   $row = explode("||",$val);
   foreach((array)$row as $key2=>$val2) {
      $data[ $categories[$key2] ][] = trim($val2);
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

your example with the above code gives:

```
Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1   
            [1] =>     
            [2] =>     
        )

    [Owner] => Array
        (
            [0] =>    John   
            [1] =>           
            [2] =>           
        )

    [Items] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  Mouse
            [1] =>  Keyboard
            [2] =>  Monitor
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but why are you include the lines in your code? The table that I show you is the table in the mysql database. It has nothing to do with my problem.Sorry if you misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the last line correctly, you want:

```
  $results = $db -> query("SELECT Items FROM table");

  while($row = $results -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $items[] = $row['Items'];
  }
```

Comment: If you are wanting the entire table as an array, you'll need to normalize your data to make it clear the ownership and id of each item.